# Checking existing project to VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have an existing solution on my dev machine.

I also created a new project on VSTS.

What's next for me? I always struggle with this. I simply don't understand the logic. When I try to map my local folder to the repository on VSTS, it wants to "Map & Get" which deletes all my files on my dev machine.

Ideally, I'd like to create a branch named "Develop" under my fresh new project repository on VSTS then check my files into it.

I'd appreciate someone telling me where to go from here. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to push your existing code into VSTS with new project repo? or you want to sync your existing code to VSTS vice versa VSTS to your local working copy

Comment: I have a new solution and a new empty repository on VSTS. I want to check my code into the repository on VSTS.

Comment: if you are using VS 2017. please check this link http://www.san2debug.net/post/getting-started-with-visual-studio-team-services.aspx or else please let me know

Comment: Thank you for response. I went through the article but the article seems to work with Git. My repository on VSTS is TFVC, not Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these steps to add solution/project to TFVC repository:

1. Open solution/project in Visual Studio
2. Open Team explorer of Visual Studio
3. Click Manage Connections icon
4. Click Manage Connections=>Connect to a project=>Select the team project=>Connect (Do not need to click Map & Get)
5. Right click the solution in Visual Studio=>Add Solution to Source Control
6. Select the corresponding folder=>Click Ok