# Unable to check in project into VSTS Repository

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm trying to check in an existing project into a fresh new repository on VSTS.

I've connected to the repository in `Team Services`. When I right click my solution and select `Add Solution to Source Control`, I get the following errors. After that nothing happens. Any idea how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: What's the detail code of solution and project files? Do these files contain these code: `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution`  
 `SccProjectName` and is there .vspscc file?Try to copy the files (solution folder) to other folder (e.g. d:/project) and try again.

Comment: Do you solve this issue? Can you provide the details of your project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an appropriate [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/create-work-workspaces) so that there is a mapping between your TFVC repository and your local file system.

Comment: I'm simply following the instructions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857909/checking-existing-project-to-vsts The answer in this post is telling me not to "map" my workspace to repository until I click to "Add solution to source control". Ever since this answer, I've been following it and it's worked every time -- except this one. Prior to this answer, I'd always map my local workspace to the repository which would try to import what's on the repo to my local workspace and damage my project. So, I'm confused as to what steps to follow.

Comment: I think this is pretty standard but I'm always starting with a project on my dev machine. I then create a repo on VSTS and check the solution in. I never find this process to be fun and end up wasting a ton of valuable time. Clearly, there are concepts I need to learn here.